# Eclipse gives compiler warning that MingGW does not

Tags: c++

Somehting about how I initialize my private class memebers.  The warning messages do not makes sense...I tried to see if they were concatenated..but they do't appear to be..this is what Eclipse is saying.  Sorry I can't format it much better.

Here are the compiler message:

```
Description                               Resource  Path    Location    Type
'sl_list<int>::node_1* sl_list<int>::head'  test_a      line 13 C/C++ Problem
when initialized here                       test_a      line 18 C/C++ Problem
'sl_list<int>::count' will be initialized   test_a      line 14 C/C++ Problem
```

**Relevant Code - call to linked_list**

```
#include "c_include_list.cpp"
#include "c_linked_list.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "sl_list" << endl;
    sl_list<int> sl_list_object;
}
```

**Relevant Code - linked_list implmentation**

```
template <class T1> class sl_list
  {
  private:

      class node_1 
      {
      public:     
        T1 data; 
        node_1 *next;
        node_1(T1 data, node_1 *next = NULL) : data(data), next(next) {}        
      };

    node_1 *head;  // line 13
      int count; // line 14

  public:

    sl_list() : count(0), head(NULL){} // line 18
```

Comment: There's no need to add the word "completed" to the title; we can see that you've accepted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple: Initialize members in the order of declaration.

```
sl_list() : head(NULL), count(0){}
```

By default, this is only a warning, so Eclipse probably gave the -Wall and -Werror flags to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

MinGW should give you this warning as well with -Wall. Private members should be initialized in the order they are declared.

(more accurately, they ARE initialized in the order they are declared; so it warns you that the order of initialization will not be as you specified it in the intialization list, in case you depend on the side effects of those initializations)